# Numpy how to calculate polynomial with large orders

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numerical-methods, hpc

I have a set of calculation involve series of very large polynomial orders, i.e.

```
f_N(x)=x**N+x**(N-1)+...+x+1
```

I needed to calculate a set of them with respect to a vector

```
F_N=[f_1,...,f_N]
X_N=[x_1,...,x_N]
```

and then evaluate with the matrix elements, which as also elements of `F_N`

```
( Matrixinverse(M(F_N,X_N)) )*F_N(X_N)
```

where `x` is most likely at integer order `1,2,3,...,1000` and increase with `N`, where `N` should run for `10,11,...,5000`. I tried to solve it with sympy. However, sympy is slow and I could at most set `N` to be in the order of 100.

So I wanted to know if it's possible to run the algorithm with Numpy. The first issue is the polynomials take large values $200^2000$, and the usual normalization by a fixed value doesn't really work since the polynomial still ran at $x^2000$. The second issue was the calculation of polynomial itself. Though numpy can handle matrix multiplication, how to calculate the thousand of orders of polynomials?

Is there a way to compute this function quickly? with numpy or some particular packages?

Comment: Have you tried [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/solvers.html)?

Comment: @MarceloPaco It's slow.